# Passing adress of a sub to a class property

Tags: c#

In VB.net I could use AdressOf when passing a sub as a parameter.

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to use delegate to pass a sub to a class property, so I can call the sub from this class.

Here's my code so far...

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AuthorizationHelper.UserHelperOptions options = new AuthorizationHelper.UserHelperOptions()
            {
                UserAuthorizedCallback = UserHelper.InitializeUser() // < problem
            };
        }
    }
}

public class UserHelper
{
    public static void InitializeUser(string userLogin)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}


// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// In another class library...
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class AuthorizationHelper
{
    public class UserHelperOptions
    {
        public delegate void UserAuthorizedCallbackDelegate(string userLogin);
        public UserAuthorizedCallbackDelegate UserAuthorizedCallback { get; set; }
    }

    public static void VerifyUser(UserHelperOptions options, string login, string password)
    {
        // If is valid user...
        options.UserAuthorizedCallback.Invoke(login);
    }
}
```

But the `UserAuthorizedCallback = UserHelper.InitializeUser()` wants me to pass the userlogin.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

This code in VB works perfectly and this is what I am trying to convert to c#...

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim options As New AuthorizationHelper.Options With {
            .Callback = AddressOf UserHelper.InitializeUser
        }
        AuthorizationHelper.VerifyUser(options, "test", "test")
    End Sub

End Module


Public Class UserHelper

    Public Shared Sub InitializeUser(userLogin As String)
        Console.WriteLine("bla bla")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Class


Public Class AuthorizationHelper

    Public Class Options
        Public Delegate Sub UserAuthorizedCallbackDelegate(userLogin As String)
        Public Property Callback As UserAuthorizedCallbackDelegate
    End Class


    Public Shared Sub VerifyUser(options As Options, login As String, password As String)
        ' If is valid user...
        options.Callback.Invoke(login)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You should remove the `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to **set** the delegate, you don´t need the parenthesis. You need them only when **executing** the delegate.

```
AuthorizationHelper.UserHelperOptions options = new AuthorizationHelper.UserHelperOptions()
{
    UserAuthorizedCallback = UserHelper.InitializeUser
};
```

When you compare that to your VB.NET-code, you´ll see it´s pretty similar:

```
Dim options As New AuthorizationHelper.Options With {
    .Callback = AddressOf UserHelper.InitializeUser // no paranthesis here
}
```

However when you want to **execute** the delegate, you need to add the the parameters in paranthesis:

```
UserAuthorizedCallback(userLogin);
```

Answer (score -1):

You declare InitializeUser(string userLogin), but then you call it without arguments. You need to add the argument when calling or structure and declare your method to not need arguments.

Comment: OP wants to pass `InitializeUser` as delegate. You won´t need to add arguments to the delegates setter. That´s the point of a delegate.